# Codedui object map/properties recording settings

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Can anyone help me with this here codedui? I can't seem to find the option to choose when doing a recording on what properties for the object map to use. like for example,

when I do a recording for a calculator or "Something" and do an action/a click on "button 1" It just directly gets all the properties like, ID, name, classname etc. for that single object.

So, my question would be is there any possible settings when recording that I could tick like just use a couple of the properties not all? (ie. ID)

BTW, I'm using VS2010 ultimate.

Cheers,
Kerwin

Answer (score 1):

UIMap editor that comes with feature pack 2 is the best solution for editing seacrh/filter properties of the control.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on something similar but haven't come up with a really good solution there are a few options but none of them are particularly user friendly or intuitive. You can hook the [UIMap save function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2010/02/02/configure-search-properties-used-by-recorder-code-generation.aspx) and prevent it from recording unwanted properties, note that this can make your tests brittle less properties generally means more failed searches. The UIMap is made by an XML file and you can parse and edit it directly. If you only have a few properties to get rid of you can use the UIMap editor that comes with feature pack 2.